# Ubuntu keyboard less responsive

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

Didn't know what happens ... suddenly the keyboard is not really responsive.

Did not have this problem before till the past 2 or 3 weeks ago.

E.g. I've to press `s` multiple times to write `press` word. Take note that `s` is just an example. It could be happen to any charter, `abc ... z` even symbol.

```
wolf@linux:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
wolf@linux:~$
```

I've been monitoring log such as `tail -f /var/log/syslog` but did not see anything when I can't press the keyboard.

What should I do to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Assuming you're using Ubuntu desktop, I'd likely explore using `xev`  (it'll show any keyboard/mouse event detected when the window is active on X).  If keys don't show there, I'd explore hardware (ie. boot a *live* system and see if it occurs there, if it's hardware the response should be identical on the *live* system, FYI: I use a very different *live* system to your installed system)

Comment: Thanks @guiverc for your feedback, yeah sometimes it didn't show up. Will try different live OS then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish there is an answer for this.

Since I don't have it and really need to use the system, I just (reformat) and reinstalled the OS from scratch and that fixed the problem.